# Packaging an ember addon in app.js instead of vendor.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there a way to bundle an ember addon in `app.js` instead of `vendor.js`. Addons seem to get packaged into `vendor.js` by default with no hooks to customize this. In this case both the app and the addon is authored by the same person.

Comment: Can you flesh out a use case?

Comment: @sheriffderek We run code obfuscation on `app.js`, and exclude `vendor.js` from it. We have a custom ember addon which we want to obfuscate as well. The approach I'm trying to take is to include it in `app.js`.

Comment: While I think that code obfuscation is not only useless but also harms users, have you considered doing that inside another addon? An addon can transform the application tree and you can simply skip over the parts you don't want to obfuscate. Maybe the source for ember-cli-uglify or other mangling addons could show you how to do this.